# C++11 threading vs. OpenMP for simple parallel loops. Which, when?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

This is something of a follow-up to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664669/c-exceptions-in-openmp-parallel-regions-what-to-do) of mine.

I would like to know if parallelized loops with a reduction operation, like a parallelized integration, belongs to the domain of applicability of C++11 threading or if OpenMP is best suited for tasks like this.

Now, consider the same setting but with threads executing computations that may throw exceptions. Does it change the scenario? Would now C++11 threading be best suited?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO, I would prefer OpenMP for any HPC / scientific and engineering computing codes. It more directly targets *data parallelism*. C++11 threading represents more *task parallelism*, which is preferable for other kinds of software (e.g., network server applications).

The situations might change in the future, there are some efforts to integrate more parallelism into C++, such as parallel STL algorithms. However, we now even do not know how this parallelism will look like.

You also rarely build codes from scratch. There are many performance-aware multi-threaded libraries that support OpenMP (sorting, linear algebra, ...), however few that support C++11 threads.

Comment: Both answers I got were really helpful. Thank you for mentioning something to the point, which is something I was overlooking: Task vs data parallelism. Thank you and I also thank @Xirema for his answer.

Answer (score 3):

As best as I can determine, OpenMP represents greater performance potential, simply because there are a lot more tricks a compiler can use (particularly if your cpu supports vectorized computations) if it can be directly instructed to parallelize a construct. Host/dispatch threading models (like the threading models in Java and C++11) can't really do that without remarkably intelligent code analysis tools.

However, OpenMP *does* represent a tax on both code readability and design flexibility. Parallel execution of heterogeneous tasks is possible in OpenMP, but much more verbose to implement, and much more difficult to parse. And because it depends on preprocessor macros (which C++ purists don't like anyways) it's virtually impossible to set dynamic state about the threading model itself.

Personally, having worked on enterprise level code, I think I prefer Host/dispatch threading (aka, C++11 threads). It may represent a performance sacrifice, but as the saying goes: "Processor Cycles are much cheaper than Developer Cycles". And if you really, *really* are in a performance constrained environment, it either means an algorithm problem, and switching to OpenMP probably wouldn't fix it; or, it means you should probably be looking into compute cards or OpenCL/Cuda programming.